# Start Download from Artifactory Remote Respository immediately

Tags: artifactory

I'm using an Artifactory Remote Repository to provide global caching behavior for certain Artifacts. However, some of these files are relatively big, and when you request them from the remote, it won't start serving any data until it's done downloading from the master. This means that downloads take nearly twice as long, and that you have a connection sitting there with no data going through, which makes timeouts a big concern.

Is there any way to configure Artifactory such that the remote will begin streaming data as it is downloaded from the master, instead of waiting until the end?
If not, does anyone have any ideas for a good workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Artifactory by default stream the requested artifact to the client while it is downloading it. I also checked this by pulling a very big Docker image using Artifactory (4.2 GB Docker image), and while Artifactory was downloading it, it also served my Docker client with it. I could verify this by pulling the same image first through Artifactory and then from Docker Hub, and it took the same amount of time to pull from both sources.

Comment: This is definitely not the behavior I'm seeing. Is there anything special about your setup?